# Printing text using Java

Tags: java, printing, network-printers

We are trying to send some text using Java to a network printer from a web application. To do a small test we have created a standalone java program and executed. Initially it all got printed with overlapping characters. After reading Orcale bug report we have changed the JRE from 1.7 to 1.6. Then everything went fine. But the same program again prints with overlapping characters if I print it using Web application. We have changed the settings in the web application to use JRE 1.6 and Tomcat 6. The program is given below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextPrint tp = new TextPrint();
        try {
            tp.textprint("test");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void textprint(String nmae) throws IOException {

        PrintService printService = getPrintService("\\\\ADMIN-PC\\TVS MSP 250 Star");
        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        try {
            PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            attributes.add(new Copies(1));
            attributes.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
            printJob.setPrintService(printService);
            attributes
                    .add(new PrinterResolution(120, 72, ResolutionSyntax.DPI));

            PageFormat pPageFormat = new PageFormat();
            Paper pPaper = pPageFormat.getPaper();
            pPaper.setSize(432, 432);
            pPaper.setImageableArea(0, 0, pPaper.getWidth(), pPaper.getHeight());
            pPageFormat.setPaper(pPaper);
            printJob.setPrintable(this, pPageFormat);
            printJob.print();
        } catch (PrinterException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void drawString(Graphics g, String line, int wc, int lineW, int y) {
        g.drawString(line, (300 - lineW) / 2, y);// center

    }

    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex)
            throws PrinterException {
        if (pageIndex > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;

        g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

        final String[][] priceTable = {
                { "1", "Paracetamol", "BAT123456", "03/20", "999", "8934.78",
                        "38865.22", "|" },
                { "2", "Distillation Water - Oral suspension (Ped)",
                        "BAT123457", "10/20", "99", "45.00", "4455.00", "|" },
                { "3", "Vicks", "BAT123458", "M05-21", "34", "453.00",
                        "15402.00", "|" },
                { "4", "Test Name ", "BAT123459", "12/21", "56", "53.00",
                        "2968.00", "|" },
                { "15", "No Name Tablets", "BAT123460", "06-22", "23",
                        "456.00", "10488.00", "|" },
                { "10", "Others", "BAT123461", "02/23", "7", "76.00", "532.00",
                        "|" } };

        String[] columnW = { "10", "27", "200", "262", "295", "312", "340",
                "410" };
        String[] columnCharLen = { "2", "30", "10", "5", "2", "7", "8", "1" };
        String[] align = { "R", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R" };
        for (int i = 0; i < priceTable.length; i++) {
            int y = 84 + (i * 12);
            for (int j = 0; j < priceTable[i].length; j++) {
                int xAxis = Integer.valueOf(columnW[j]);
                int xChar = Integer.valueOf(columnCharLen[j]);
                int diff = xChar - priceTable[i][j].length();
                if (diff > 0 && align[j].equalsIgnoreCase("R")) {
                    xAxis = (int) (xAxis + (diff * 5.6));
                }
                System.out.println(" X for - " + priceTable[i][j] + " - "
                        + xAxis);
                graphics.drawString(priceTable[i][j], xAxis, y);//
            }
        }

        /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
```

Comment: Does the computer that runs the code have a JRE 1.7 installed? Specifying 1.6 compliance doesn't necessarily mean that the code is run by a 1.6 JRE.

Comment: Yes it has. It has both JRE 1.6 & JRE 1.7. But we ran the program using eclipse where all the settings points to JRE 1.6. However, thats something we will try by removing JRE 1.7 completely.

Comment: Check the Run/Debug configurations for your project. Make sure they point to JRE 1.6.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. Though we had all the settings pointing to JRE 1.6, only after complete removal of JRE 1.7 from teh server system, we were able to get the right printing from Dot matrix printer. Not sure when Orcale is gonna fix this.

Comment: Try [TextPrinter](http://java4less.com/textprinter/Documentation.html)